# My kubuntu is taking so long to enter the desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu

I'm using the latest version of kubuntu on my dell G15 5511 core i7-11800H, 16 GB of RAM, RTX 3050 and SSD.
The thing is, I'm new to linux and I'm using dual boot windows 11 and kubuntu, while my windows 11 boots in almost no time (literally it's almost instantaneously), kubuntu takes about 2 mins (or more) to enter the desktop after typing my password, this behavior is kind of new it wasn't always like that, I mean it was developed over time, any ideas how can I fix this
#############################

EDIT: I ran the '''systemd-analyze blame''' and '''systemd-analyze critical-chain''' like @archismanpanigrahi asked and here is the output[systemd-analyze blame output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrLk.png)
[systemd-analyze blame output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWJAI.png)
[systemd-analyze critical-chain output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzMO5.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.

Comment: *my windows 11 boots in almost no time (literally it's almost instantaneously)* No, not really, it's because it never shuts down properly due to the Fast Startup feature introduced in Windows 8.1 and something that MUST be disabled when dual-booting.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi sure, just a sec

Comment: @ChanganAuto Oh, I didn't know that, How can I disable it please

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi done editing